# Syncing OSX dot files with github

Tags: git, macos, github

I would like to keep a copy of certain dot files in my OSX home folder on a GitHub repo. However, I do not want to include files and folders such as Documents/, Downloads/, etc ...  what would be the best way of achieving this?

Is it better to ignore the all files/folders (of current dir) in .gitignore whitelisting only the desired ones:

```
/* 

!.vimrc, 
!.bash_profile, etc
```

or the opposite:

```
Documents/
Downloads/
Pictures/
```

or some other way?

Thank you

Comment: Why not create a repo and symbolic links to it from the home directory?

Answer (score 2):

See [Managing Dotfiles with Git](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/managing_dotfiles_with_git.html) from [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) (currently Microsoft, previously GitHub):
you can create a git repo elswhere

```
git clone --separate-git-dir=.dotfiles.git ethomson.visualstudio.com:DefaultCollection/personal/_git/dotfiles .
rm .git
echo '*' > .dotfiles.git/info/exclude
```

(Use the remote repo you want: Edward uses a TFS Git one)

And then add your dotfiles with an alias like:

```
alias dotfiles="git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles.git"
```

You can do:

```
dotfiles add .zshrc
dotfiles commit 
dotfiles push
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat old, had forgotten about this post.  Anyway, I've now set up my dotfiles and sync them with github in a way that is quite easy and practical.  Going off of what @theoden suggested in the comments, these are the steps I took ...

```
mkdir ~/.dotfiles
```

and move all the config/dotfiles I want on github such as .bashrs, .bash_aliases, vimrc etc. with ...

```
mv file file2 file3 ~/.dotfiles
```

then create symbolic links of those files to the home dir ...

```
ln -sf ~/.dotfilles/file ~
```

the -f flag is force to overwrite existing files if present.  Create a git repo in ~/.dotfiles and use that to push to github ...

```
git init
```

I also added *.swp, *.swo to .git/info/exclude to ignore swap files.
And then I wrote a little script to automate the process of the symlinks, in case I need to set up my system again, that way I can just clone the repo from github and run the script to create all necessary symlinks to make the system work. Here is the script ...

```
#!/bin/bash
#creates dotfile symlinks in home

ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/.bash* ~
ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/.gitconfig ~
ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/.vimrc ~
ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/.config/neofetch/config.conf ~/.config/neofetch/
rm -f ~/.bash*_bak
rm -f ~/.bash*-bak
```

works very well for me.  Hope this can help somebody else.

Comment: Interesting feedback. +1. More specific than my answer.

Comment: @VonC. Thank you. And thank you for posting the link. The article did help a lot when I was figuring out the best set-up for my dotfiles. It's an informative article, learned a lot.